# "Quel est" ou "Qui est", lequel utiliser ?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, questions

Je viens de tomber sur la phrase suivante

> **Quel** est le professeur des Sciences Naturelles ?

Pour moi la formulation correcte doit être

> **Qui** est le professeur des Sciences Naturelles ?

Ai-je raison ? Quelle est la règle qui permet de trancher en faveur d'une des deux formulations ?

Comment: Quel qu'il en soit, quel et qui sont tels qu'ils sont, à quelques sons près ils se ressemblent dans la leçon, mais ne vont pas comme l'avoine et le son se rassembler, Antoine.

Comment: Je suis d'accord avec M. Faidébonne sur la relation intrinsèque qui existe entre les deux protagonistes, ici à l'étude. Toutefois, le son est bien plus que l'enveloppe de l'avoine et ne devrait jamais être étudié avec cette dernière de façon plurielle. Le danger de se perdre dans dans conjectures guette l'érudit qui emprunte le sentier hors-piste de la connaissance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La formule

> Quel est le professeur des Sciences Naturelles ?

sous-entend en général que celui qui pose la question connaît un nombre limité de professeurs parmi lesquels il veut identifier ledit professeur de Sciences Naturelles.

Alors que la formule

> Qui est le professeur des Sciences Naturelles ?

est plus ouverte, et qu'a priori celui qui pose la question ne sait pas qui cela pourrait être.

Answer (score 5):

Les deux sont corrects.  Voir par exemple [l'entrée du TLFi](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/quel) qui note que quand l’antécédent est un pronom à la première ou deuxième personne, *quel* est rarement utilisé.  *Quel* peut être utilisé dans des contextes où il n'est pas équivalent à *qui*, quand l'interrogation porte sur une qualité plutôt que sur l'identité.

Personnellement, je trouve l'utilisation que *quel* quand *qui* est possible plutôt vieillie.